# How to debug npm package on the interactive console?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I want to play with the library interactively.

I've created base npm project with `npm init`
Then put the library to dependencies in package.json
Then `npm install`

Then created index.js with following code

```js
import csc from "country-state-city";

debugger
```

Then `node inspect index.js`
it stops on the `debugger` word, but csc variable is not accessible.

But when I write `console.log(csc)` instead
and run it returns a correct object.

How to make it possible to play with any npm package interactively?